# In Swift 4.2 - How can I animate a circle in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, animation, sprite-kit

I am able to draw a circle at the collision point of two objects, but I want to create a nice animation for it (clockwise). I understood how to do it in single view application but I can't use the same implementation in SpriteKit. How can I do it in SpriteKit?

This is my code for adding a circle -

```
func drawCircleOnCollisionPoint(arrowName:String) {
    let circle:SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
    circle.position = (arrowsCollidedWithTarget[arrowName]?.contactPoint)!
    circle.strokeColor = SKColor.red
    circle.glowWidth = 1.0
    circle.fillColor = SKColor.clear
    circle.zPosition = 50
    self.addChild(circle)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + timeBetweenGames) {
        circle.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to animate it? Alpha? Scale? Try fiddling with `SKAction` and `SKSpriteNode.run(_:)` methods.

Comment: I want a closing circle animation if that make sense..? Start with nothing on the screen and then a circle is drawn (I hope you understand what I mean - I can add a gif if its necessary)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

let action = SKAction.rotate(byAngle: -360, duration: 30)

circle.run(SKAction.repeatForever(action))

Comment: I don't see any difference.. I am running the action right before I am adding the circle as a child. I also tried running the action after adding the child...